# QGIS dissolving lines

Tags: qgis, dissolve

I have a line (pipe) network. Based on 3 attributes (material, dimension, location-street) I created new attribute with the same material, dimension and location. Now I want to dissolve the network based on this new attribute. Problem is, often location is "Null" (pipe is not in the street). Simple dissolving therefore create many multiparts with same material and dimension. These multiparts are often not part of the same line, e.g. multiparts with 2 parallel segments or simply far from each other.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It will be very helpful if you post the solution in the answer section.

Comment: So I partly solved the problem. First, I used dissolve function. Then I selected all features with location "NULL" and used function split feature part. Hovewer, it does not work perfectly. If two branches of network with the same attributes join together, it dissolve both branches. I need not to dissolve these two branches .

Comment: redirected problem to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/401153/qgis-dissolving-joining-lines