# Dissolving joining lines in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dissolve, polyline-creation

I dissolve lines with the same attributes. However, if these lines join, they cannot be dissolved. How can it be done?

[image]

Comment: So you want to concatenate the attributes to AB? Do you only have one attribute which is the column with the A and B?

Answer (score 1):

Use the ["Aggregate"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#aggregate) tool from the QGIS's Processing Toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
and set the attribute containing the values for `A` and `B` as `Group by expression`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dissolve algorithm with field selected to make dissolution only for those that have common algorithm.

And then use multipart to single part to have only connected lines. I think it should work well. If not share the result of step 1 and step 2.

Comment: How can I find automaticaly  lines with common algorithm?

Comment: the multipart to single part would do this i think.

Comment: @pazelvak does the tool work or not ?

Comment: The multipart to single part tool doesnt work.